# How do I Add injection to constructor of an extensible controller in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container, mef

Using Unity with MVC4 I'm able to target extension controllers just fine. And I'm also able to inject to the constructor of a local controller while still having all the extensible controllers available. I just can't seem to find a way to do inject into the constructor of an extensible controller. I tried MEF as well with even less success.

I'm looking for links to sample code that does this and any suggestions are welcome. I have mock-up code for testing and can post it if needed.

Comment: I use structuremap mvc and it works as a charm

Comment: And structuremap works with both extensions and injection? Correction to above, I'm using Unity with  MEF integrated into it.